# Find the movement speed of a UIView using a NSTimer or CADisplayLink

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, nstimer

I have a very fast scrolling UIScrollView containing many views which are updated when they are reused.

When the scrollview scrolls fast I would like the views to disregard any new drawing they may need to do (which requires fetching info from disk such as images etc.)

I thought about creating a CADisplayLink (or in this case an NSTimer) and calculating the views position changed in the keywindow like so

```
- (void)setupUpdateTimer
{
    self.shouldUpdateCoverPhoto = YES;
    self.previousFrame = CGRectNull;
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:UpdateInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerUpdate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.updateTimer = timer;

}

-(void)timerUpdate:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    CGRect currentFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertRect:self.frame fromView:self.superview];
    CGRect previousFrame = self.previousFrame;
    self.previousFrame = currentFrame;
    if (CGRectEqualToRect(previousFrame, CGRectNull))
    {
        self.shouldUpdateCoverPhoto = YES;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat distance = ABS(currentFrame.origin.y - previousFrame.origin.y);
    CGFloat speed = ABS(distance/UpdateInterval);
    DLog(@"Speed is %f",speed);
    if (speed < 1000)
    {

        self.shouldUpdateCoverPhoto = YES;
    } else {

        self.shouldUpdateCoverPhoto = NO;
    }
}
```

But the timer callback isn't called on a regular basis when the view changes position very fast.

So I don't know what the view position change is on a regular enough basis.

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**

Here is a possible solution  (in the spirit of the question) that I conjured up for very fast scrolling (not necessarily in a scroll view that you have access to your delegates).

```
- (void)setupUpdateTimer
{
    self.shouldUpdateCoverPhotoOnSlowLoop = NO;
    self.previousFrame = CGRectNull;
    self.scrollSpeed = 0;

    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkNeedsUpdate:)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void)checkNeedsUpdate:(CADisplayLink *)link
{

    CGRect currentFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertRect:self.frame fromView:self.superview];
    CGRect previousFrame = self.previousFrame;
    self.previousFrame = currentFrame;
    if (CGRectEqualToRect(previousFrame, CGRectNull))
    {
        self.scrollSpeed = 0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat distance = ABS(currentFrame.origin.y - previousFrame.origin.y);
    CGFloat duration = link.duration;
    CGFloat speed = ABS(distance/duration);


    self.scrollSpeed = speed;
    if (self.scrollSpeed < ThreasholdSpeedForCoverPhotoUpdate && self.shouldUpdateCoverPhotoOnSlowLoop)
    {
        [self setCoverPhotoForUser:_user];
    }

}

-(void)setCoverPhotoForUser:(id <InviGenericUserProtocol>)user
{
    if (self.scrollSpeed > ThreasholdSpeedForCoverPhotoUpdate && self.coverPhotoImageView.image != nil)
    {
        self.shouldUpdateCoverPhotoOnSlowLoop = YES;
        //DLog(@"Scroll speed %f greater than threashold %d - Not updating cover photo",self.scrollSpeed,ThreasholdSpeedForCoverPhotoUpdate);
        return;
    }
    self.shouldUpdateCoverPhotoOnSlowLoop = NO;

    [self loadCoverPhotoForUser:user completion:^(UIImage *image){
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{self.coverPhotoImageView.image = image;}
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `NSTimer` but use the `UIScrollView delegate` for this.

To calculate the scroll speed:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat scrollSpeed = scrollView.contentOffset.y - previousScrollViewYOffset;
    previousTableViewYOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for( UIViewSubclass *subview in scrollView ){
    subView.shouldUpdateCoverPhoto = scrollSpeed < kMaxScrollSpeed;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't in this particular situation as I needed a more general solution (not only for scroll views). I will post a possible solution I conjured up.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need a more general solution, like without scrollViews. How are they scrolling fast then?

Comment: I have a view inside a view inside a view etc. There is no way to trickle the scroll speed to every possible subview that could want to handle such an event. Also a custom view might have no knowledge of its container - it may decide in certain circumstances that fetching resource from disk or network is futile in a case where it wouldn't be displayed - for instance if the view was "flying" out of the screen. That is a certain use case that I was facing

Answer (score 0):

How about `UIScrollView` delegate method:

```
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:?
```

Isn't it what you want?

Comment: That would be the best of course, but I don't have that option in this particular case. I need a more general solution